# Python find x value to corresponding max y value in plot

Tags: python, average, max

I've plotted a moving average from about 300,000 data points and I need to find the maximum y-value for the peak in the signal and its corresponding x-value, which would be its frequency. I'd like for it to give me the coordinates on the plot itself but if I can get it to at least print them out I'd be satisfied. Excuse my programming skills as they are not the strongest. Here's the section of the code I'm working on and a link to the plot that it generates. I don't have enough points to post the image.

```
def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
    window= np.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
    return np.convolve(interval, window, 'same')

x = freq[0:300000]
y = fft
pylab.plot(x,y,"k.")
y_av = movingaverage(y, 30)
pylab.plot(x, y_av,"r")
pylab.xlim(0,10)
pylab.ylim(0,1500)
pylab.xlabel("Frequency")
pylab.ylabel("Moving Average Magnitude")
pylab.grid(True)
pylab.show()
```

[Moving Average Plot](http://i256.photobucket.com/albums/hh161/KyLayfield/Plot.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
max_y = max(y_av)  # Find the maximum y value
max_x = x[y_av.index(max_y)]  # Find the x value corresponding to the maximum y value
print max_x, max_y
```

---

**Edit**

numpy arrays do not have an index method, so we should use argmax, as pointed out in the comments:

```
max_y = max(y_av)  # Find the maximum y value
max_x = x[y_av.argmax()]  # Find the x value corresponding to the maximum y value
print max_x, max_y
```

---

I think [this API](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) should work to let you draw text onto your image.  You could do that like so:

```
pylab.text(max_x, max_y, str((max_x, max_y)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I run the code with those changes I get this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Since y_av is a numpy array, it does not have an index method. However, you could do `max_x = x[y_av.argmax()]` instead.

Comment: Actually, this is giving me the maximum value for both x and y across the entire axis. I'm wanting to find the x-axis value for the maximum y-value. So in the plot I have linked, the maxiumum y-value of the moving average was found to be 1191.07 so the frequency should be roughly 1.2~1.3. I limited the axis since the data was sampled at 1000Hz and the frequency can detect up to 500Hz.

Comment: So, `y_av.argmax()` should give you the index of the largest value in `y_av`.  Is `max(y_av)` equal to `y_av[y_av.argmax()]`?  What value is `x[y_av.argmax()]` giving you?

Comment: max(y_av) = 1191.07, y_av[y_av.argmax()] = 1191.07, and x[y_av.argmax()] = 498.71

Comment: Hmmmm.  Is pyplot messing around with the scaling of your data?  What is `x[-1]`?  If that's more than 10, do you need to scale `x[y_av.argmax()]` to get it to match up with your axes.  If it's not, I'm kind of at a loss -- `y_av.argmax()` clearly finds the index of the maximum value in `y_av`, and that value should be plotted at `x[y_av.argmax()]`, since you're plotting `y_av` versus `x`.

Comment: It works now, I had to cut down the arrays. Thanks for the help, Sam!